# How to mount Anderson connector on PCB

Tags: connector

I'm trying to mate with a [P992G1 Anderson connector](https://canada.newark.com/anderson-power-products/p992g1/plug-socket-housing-2-position/dp/16R1516) and need to find a suitable PCB-mount receptacle to design into my board (footprint, STEP model, etc.). The P992G1 is connected to a battery/solar panel set up that will power my PCB.

I looked around on Newark's website and it seems they have some that will match with this but not in stock. I couldn't find anything suitable on DigiKey or Mouser, which seems odd because there must be a popular receptacle used by everyone to connect to their PCB...

Comment: The datasheet show many PCB contact options. what? You can’t find stock and need help finding stock

Comment: I found stock https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Anderson-Power-Products/PC5934T-BK?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtjzVbpKqo2YZRH3O%252BLIhj70PQmWeNNemY%3D. what did U not try?